# Visual Studio 2008 running in virtualbox cannot compile files on a shared folder

Tags: visual-studio, installation, virtualization, virtualbox

Im using virtualbox's own shared folders to share my source directory from my mac to my windows virtualbox. It turns out that it cannot compile any solution that is located on the shared drive.

It fails to compile the files since it cannot find obj\Debug\.tmp.
It says that that file is not a valid win32-resource file yet, when I look for it it doesn't exist.

> Error 1   'S:\experiment\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\obj\Debug\CSCA3A1.tmp'
>   is not a valid Win32 resource file    WindowsFormsApplication1

I've added FullTrust to the networkshare using Caspol so there shouldn't be any security issues. I can save files to the share and modify them. Running msbuild on the solution file produces the same errors.

How do I fix this?

this is the output when running msbuild on the same solution:

> Build FAILED.
>
> "S:\experiment\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1.sln"
>   (default target) (1) ->
>   "S:\experiment\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsAp
>   plication1.csproj" (default target) (2) -> (CoreCompile target) ->
>   CVTRES : fatal error CVT1103: cannot read file   CSC : error CS1583:
>   's:\experiment\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsAppli
>   cation1\obj\Debug\CSCA1A9.tmp' is not a valid Win32 resource file
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 2 Error(s)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there was an issue with Windows7 x64 guests and shared folders in VirtualBox version 4.1.0. I upgraded to the latest version 4.1.2 (released yesterday) and now compiling works like a charm.

Comment: Lucky me, the bug bit me 3 day after they release update, not before ;-) Thank you for sharing the info.